# HTML Share to facebook / twitter cut my link

Tags: html, facebook

I had to work on my showroom url. When you click on a project, a pop-up is shown with this url :

example.org/en/showroom/#projName

So I changed the url with js blablabla and when I inspect my page, I have what I want for the sharing button.
For fb example :
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A//example.org/en/showroom/#jaguar

But when I click on the button, the fb pop-up opening has this url :
example.org/en/showroom/

This is so weird. Is it not just a string ? Does the '#' messing with it ?

Comment: You need to properly URL-encode the parameter value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the built-in function `escape()`, `encodeURIComponent(str)` and `encodeURI(str)`.

You have three options:

`escape()` will not encode: @*/+

`encodeURI()` will not encode: ~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'

`encodeURIComponent()` will not encode: ~!*()'

The character encoding used with escape is variable. 
So I would stick with encodeURI and encodeURIComponent, which use UTF-8.

[Sifference between encodeURI() and encodeURIComponent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)